# Time Complexity of loop that contains recursive function

Tags: loops, recursion, time, complexity-theory

I've got a difficulty working the time complexity of the following code:

```
int f(int n)  {

int x=1;
for (int k=0; k<n; k++){
x *=n*n
} 
g(n);
return x; }
```

Where g(n) is a recursive function:

```
void g(int n){
   if (n<1)
     return;
g(n/2);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: These are general questions, I didn't notice that g(n) is outside the loop, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexity of `g(n)` is `O(log n)`.

Complexity of `f(n)` is `O(n + log n)` (`n` for the `for` loop, `log n` for the call to `g(n)`) -- or simply `O(n)` as pointed out by Shipra Gupta.

```
int f(int n)  {
  int x=1;
  for (int k=0; k < n; k++) { // O(n)
    x *= n*n // O(1)
  } 
  g(n); // O(log n)
  return x;
}
```

`O(n * 1 + log(n) + 1)`

That is, if we ignore the fact that `g(n)` will never reach the `n<1` condition, if `n >= 1` (stack overflow!) ... speaking of which -- welcome to the site! :-P

Comment: I didn't notice that g(n) is outside the loop. Thank you for your help and welcome!!

Comment: If `g(n)` was inside the function, you'd simply multiply its complexity by the amount of times it is called, resulting in `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 2):

```
int f(int n)  {
int x=1;
// O(n) time complexity due to for loop
for (int k=0; k < n; k++) { 
  // O(1) 
  x *= n*n 
} 
// O(log n)(base 2) because for every time we divide by 2 before calling the function 
g(n); 
return x;
}
void g(int n){
 if (n<1)
  return;
 g(n/2);
}
```

Now O(logn) is faster than O(n) which means that the overall time complexity of the code is O(n) simply!!

Comment: didn't notice that g(n) is outside the loop, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ron73404 please upvote and accept the answer if you find it useful :)